# What are the numbers associated with printing getchar()?

Tags: c, printf, getchar, putchar

Code:

```
int main(void) {

    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d", c);
    }
   
}
```

I enter a character and that character is returned with putchar(c), however, if I print that character I get a code back? example:

0 = 48010

1 = 49110

2 = 50210

etc...

what are these numbers? is this where the character is stored in memory or something?
cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your exact output. You do not print `0 = ` anywhere in your code.

Comment: You might notice that `'0' == 48`, `'1' == 49` ...

Comment: When I run this program, the visual studio terminal opens and I can type values in the terminal. When I type a value such as 1 it returns 49110. When I simply press enter in the terminal it returns 10.

Comment: You might want to change `printf("%d", c);` to `printf("%d\n", c);`.

Comment: @YohoraPancake: If you want to show us a large amount of additional code, you can either [edit] your question or, if it is an answer to your own question, you can post your own answer. Comments are not designed for posting large amounts of code.

Comment: In the "48010" I can see the ascii code for "0" the "0" itself, the ASCII code for linefeed and the line feed itself, because the following output is in the next line. All of that could be produced by your code, assuming you alternate typing digits and the enter key, or you read in a text file with single digits in each new line. What I do not see is how your code might produce the "0 =" and "1 = " etc. It is hence very important that you double and triple check that the shown code and the shown output match. Also please be very clear, precise and detailed about the input you use.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I figured out the problem by introducing newlines

```
    int main(void) {

    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        printf("\n");
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", c);
    
    }

}
```

When I enter 1 this returns the following in the terminal window.

49

1

10

What's happening is I'm returning the ASII character code for 1 - > 49

returning the value I entered with getchar()

and returning 10 which is the linefeed value i.e. the enter command.

Right? without the newlines it was just concatenating them all, making it confusing.

Comment: Yes, so you confirm everything I wrote in my comment. I feel a little strange about this.

Comment: apologies I wrote this before I read your comment. :)

Comment: Ad please learn about correct representation of the actual output and about being clear about the input you provide.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. Does not change anything about the unclear input and output info you provide. Please take the highly recommended [tour] (I know that you did not bother yet) and read [ask] and [mre]. Then I chalk that up as a beinnger making an honest attempt at learning. Beginners mistakes are forgiven. Good luck. Have fun at StackOverflow.

Comment: Peace offer :-) :If you read the links and improve your question so that the answer can really be seen by analysing your infos, then I will even upvote the question.